# How can I process arguments with Python in command line?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm just new to Python and I want to ask:

How can I process input values from command line with Python? For example:

./mathpy.py *--plus* **2** **5**

result: **7**

or

./mathpy.py --max **2** **5**

result: **5**

Some examples would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Next time, use Google to search for your question, and relevant answers on SO will appear at the top. Also, while you are composing your question, a list entitled **Questions that may already have your answer** shows up with potentially relevant questions. **Use that list** and open up the suggested questions in new tabs. This site has been around for over 6 years, if you suspect a question has already been asked, it probably has. Duplicates like this just waste time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at **argparse** module:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html